# The term 'swift' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code

While executing swift in vscode I am getting this error:

```
swift : The term 'swift' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path  
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ swift "c:\Users\Aditya\Documents\Wings Bionic\Pulse generator\app.swi ...
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (swift:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
```

I have installed the Swift extension by Swift Server Work Group.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. As an advice for your first question, the title should feature what you want to achieve instead of the error you are encountering. In the body of your question, you must specify what you are achieving and where you get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use vs code in windows:

uninstall **swift** extension [Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QNwv.jpg)

and install **swift-sfdc** extension.[swift-sfdc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsB8t.jpg)

Restart VS Code and try.

optional: if you didn't add path in environment variables then add